# Python import works one way but not another

Tags: python, python-3.x, structure, python-import, project

I am a little confused by the way things can be imported in Python (v3.11.0). I have the following project structure:

```
/main
    __init__.py
    main.py

    /sub
        __init__.py
        load_me.py
```

The file `load_me.py` includes a function `run_me`.

Running the function the following way works:

```
from sub import load_me

load_me.run_me()
```

However the following gives me `AttributeError: module 'sub' has no attribute 'load_me'`:

```
import sub

sub.load_me.run_me()
```

Is there an error in my project structure or is this intended behaviour and if so, what are the reasons?

Comment: The "module" `sub` in the error means actually the `__init__.py` module in the directory `sub`. You can only access in the latter way what this module imported or created.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you didn't actually import the load_me module, only the package it's in. Do this instead:

```
import sub.load_me

sub.load_me.run_me()
```